# Select Values from dataframe if it is not NaN in another dataframe with same size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I want to select values from df1 if it is not NaN in df2. And keep the replace the rest in df1 as NaN.

DF1

| Case | Path1 | Path2 | Path3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 321 | 333 |
| 2 | 456 | 654 | 444 |
| 3 | 789 | 987 | 555 |
| 4 | 1011 | 1101 | 666 |
| 5 | 1112 | 2105 | 777 |

DF2

| Case | Path1 | Path2 | Path3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | NaN | a | NaN |
| 4 | NaN | NaN | a |
| 5 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

I want the output to be like this

| Case | Path1 | Path2 | Path3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | NaN | 987 | NaN |
| 4 | NaN | NaN | 666 |
| 5 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Comment: Maybe something like `df1.mask(df2.isna())` or equivalent `df1.where(df2.notna())`?

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs it depends if "Case" should be a matching key. Relying on the index might be risky in this case ;)

Comment: I agree, that's why I made a comment, not an answer :,) OP should clarify

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you need to match on "Case".

If this is the case first [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) then [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) using [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html), finally [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
out = df1.set_index('Case').mask(df2.set_index('Case').isna()).reset_index()
```

Else, just `mask`:

```
out = df1.mask(df2.isna())
```

Output:

```
   Case  Path1  Path2  Path3
0     1  123.0    NaN    NaN
1     2    NaN    NaN    NaN
2     3    NaN  987.0    NaN
3     4    NaN    NaN  666.0
4     5    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are same index and columns in both DataFrames use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html):

```
df = df1.mask(df2.isna())
print (df)

   Case  Path1  Path2  Path3
0     1  123.0    NaN    NaN
1     2    NaN    NaN    NaN
2     3    NaN  987.0    NaN
3     4    NaN    NaN  666.0
4     5    NaN    NaN    NaN
```